# Extract Option from Future in ActionBuilder

Tags: scala, playframework, future, scala-option, actionbuilder

I am implementing authentication based on this [Scala Play Authentication](https://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-play-auth/) example.

Therefore I use the following `ActionBuilder` to build an `UserAction`.

`UserAction.scala`

```scala
class UserRequest[A](val user: Option[Admin], request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

class UserAction @Inject()(adminService: AdminService, parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends ActionBuilder[UserRequest, AnyContent]
    with ActionTransformer[Request, UserRequest] {

  def transform[A](request: Request[A]) = Future.successful {

    val sessionTokenOpt = request.session.get("sessionToken")

    val user = sessionTokenOpt
      .flatMap(token => Sessions.getSession(token))
      .filter(_.expiration.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)))
      .map(_.email)
       // Signature: getAdminByEmail(email: String): Future[Option[Admin]]
      .flatMap(adminService.getAdminByEmail) // <- Extract Future here

    // The user has to be Option[Admin] but is Future[Option[Admin]]
    // because of adminService.getAdminByEmail
    new UserRequest(user, request)
  }
}
```

Since the [example implementation in line 25](https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-auth-example/blob/master/app/controllers/helpers/UserAction.scala#L25) does not return a Future because there is no database setup included, I get the following error:

```scala
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Option[models.Tables.Admin]]
 required: Option[?]
```

Because I am new to scala I have no clue how to extract the Future at this point. How to handle the Future result to make sure we return a `Option[Admin]`?

Comment: I am happy for you that you did it on your own. This is usually more beneficial. For next time, please create a [mcve]. It is really hard to answer such questions when we don't know what is the signature of `adminService.getAdminByEmail` for example.

Comment: The signature is available as comment inside the code. But I try to be more explicit next time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it on my own. I just divided the email and fetching into two different parts and moved the `Future` inside the `email match`.

```scala
class UserAction @Inject()(adminService: AdminService, val parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
  extends ActionBuilder[UserRequest, AnyContent]
    with ActionTransformer[Request, UserRequest] {

  def transform[A](request: Request[A]) : Future[UserRequest[A]] = {
    val sessionTokenOpt = request.session.get("sessionToken")

    val email = sessionTokenOpt
      .flatMap(token => Sessions.getSession(token))
      .filter(_.expiration.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)))
      .map(_.email)

    email match {
      case Some(value) =>
        adminService.getAdminByEmail(value).map(a => new UserRequest(a, request))
      case None =>
        Future { new UserRequest(None, request) }
    }
  }
}
```